# Sign out from multiple applications

Tags: oauth-2.0, thinktecture-ident-server, openid-connect

I'm working on an OpenID Connect implementation, that is going to work as a single sign-on for multiple 
applications. I get how to sign out a user from a single application or simply revoke refresh 
tokens for further renewal of access tokens. But from looking at Google's implementation; when you sign out from Gmail you are immediately signed out from all other Google apps like; YouTube, Google + etc.

How is such behavior accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID has the concept of single sign out - but the spec is still in draft:

http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html

IdentityServer v3 does not implement this spec right now - but it is planned for RTM.